# javascript return time to closest quarter

Tags: javascript, time

Having an input field with time given like hh:mm.

Any one having a function that

1. check for correct time syntax.
2. change to `:` if anything else eg. `.,;` is entered separating hour and minutes.
3. format time to closest 15 min. eg. 05 -> 00, 08 -> 15.

Edit: 
Input comes from this:

```
<input name=event_time_end id=event_time_end type=text maxlengt=5 size=5 value='' onblur='toTime(this);'>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution enforces syntax, removes excess characters and formats the result as a valid time:

```js
console.clear();
function closestQuarter(n) {
 return (Math.round(n % 60 / 15) * 15) % 60;
}
function toTime(str) {
 str = str
  //Replace non-digist with ':'
  .replace(/(?:\D*)?\D+/g, ':')
  //Replace first ':' with '*' to give us a target
  .replace(':', '*')
  //Remove ':'
  .replace(/:/g, '')
  //Split by '*'
  .split('*');
 //In case of empty string
 if (str.length < 1) {
  str.push('00');
 }
 //In case of only hours
 if (str.length < 2) {
  str.push('00');
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].length > 2) {
   str[i] = str[i].substr(0, 2);
  }
  if (str[i].length == 0) {
   str[i] = '00';
  }
 }
 //Force 0-23
 str[0] = (parseInt(str[0]) % 24).toString();
 //Round to quarter
 str[1] = closestQuarter(parseInt(str[1])).toString();
 //Prepend '0' if needed
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].length < 2) {
   str[i] = '0' + str[i];
  }
 }
 //Return a ':' joined string
 return str.join(':')
}
//Tests
console.log([toTime('21:45'),
  toTime('21:4'),
  toTime('1:3'),
  toTime('1.3'),
  toTime('1.3i3'),
  toTime('13.37pm')
 ]);

function displayInHTML() {
 //Get value from element
 var input = (document.getElementById("time").value).toString();
 var output = document.getElementById("output");
 output.innerHTML = toTime(input);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="time" name="time" onkeyup="displayInHTML()"/>
<textarea style="width:100%" id="output" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Weird. Running the snippet - no errors. Copy paste -and TypeError: str.join is not a function

Comment: What browser and browser version?

Comment: FireFox version 47.0.1
And just to verify - alert(str) and alert(str[1]) gives "object HTMLInputElement]"

Comment: Ahh^^ My bad. You weren't supposed to send the entire element to this function, just its value. This way you can easier reuse the function. I have updated the snippet to show you have to get the value from the element.

Comment: Possible to just replace the element value?

Answer (score 2):

You can divide minutes by 15 and multiply the rounded result with 15 for the right quarter.

```js
var minutes;

for (minutes = 0; minutes < 60; minutes++) {
    console.log(minutes + ': ' + (Math.round(minutes / 15) * 15));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To round a number of minutes to the nearest quarter you can use:

```
var x = minutes + 7;
minutes = x - (x % 15)
```

```js
var minutes, x;
for (minutes = 0; minutes <= 50; minutes++) {
    x = minutes + 7;
    console.log(minutes + ' : ' + (x - (x % 15)));
}
```